# End of Input in a Visual Studio 2013 C++ Console Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I made a C++ program in Visual Studio 2013 that takes in inputs using

```
while (getline(cin, strLine))
{
    ...
}
```

When I try to signal end of input in the Visual Studio console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, it just inputs "^D". Is that not the right command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Windows, but probably following instructions for some other system. The Windows console end-of-file indicator is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.